# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Xc', but it was: a custom MouseEvent object

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to update a value in my collection :

```
const docRef = collection(db, "Forecaster_init");

  async function isOkay(docRef) {
    await updateDoc((docRef),'Forecast01'), {
nameStated: true }};
```

but it's not working i don't know why ... "a custom MouseEvent object"

ForeCast01 is the Doc id

any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just that code snippet on its own looks correct. Can you edit your question and add complete code so we can see where are those values of `docRef` or any other params you pass are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
  import '/fonts.css';
  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import {getFirestore, collection, onSnapshot, updateDoc, addDoc}       from "firebase/firestore";
    import {firebaseConfig} from './src/lib/Firebase.js';
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

    

  const ArrayCall = writable(0);

  ArrayCall.subscribe(value => {
  }); // logs '0'

  // if getprojectname on bdd is false alors
    let yes = false;
  let display = false;
      const handleClick = () => display = !display;

    let projectName = ''; // à redéfinir
  let DashName = '';
  let Pseudo = '';

    // Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore();

    import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

    const docRef = collection(db, "Forecaster_init");
    const osef = onSnapshot(docRef, (querySnapshot) => {

    const Array = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { myPseudo, projectName, nameStated } = doc.data();
      Array.push({
            id: doc.id,
        myPseudo,
        projectName,
        nameStated
        });
    
// insert values array on variable;
  ArrayCall.set(Array[0]); 
    });
  });   

  async function isOkay(docRef) {
        await updateDoc((docRef),'Forecast01'), {
    nameStated: true
  }};

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your return, here my script (it's on svelte js)

Comment: While providing a code-only answer may answer the question, it’s recommended to provide an explanation for any additions or edits made. That way, future readers can understand your solution. Please [edit] your answer to add context and/or an explanation to your code.